# Multiselect option with remove button, and assigning class/id to each selected item differently

Tags: jquery, html

```
Select numbers (you can select each number any number of times):

 <select name="number_selection" method="post" id="number_selection" >
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
 <input type="button" value="Select" id="select_button"/> 


 <div id="feedback"> </div>
```

This is the jquery i've written to select and deselect:

```
$('#select_button_gs').click(function(){
    var gs= $('#slct_fcb_gs').val();
    $('#fcb_pt_gs').append('<span>' + gs + '</span>' + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="gs_remove" />' + '<br>');

    });

    $('#fcb_pt_gs').on('click','.gs_remove',function(){
         $(this).prev('span').remove();
         $(this).next('br').remove();
          $(this).remove();  
       });
```

Now,  What should I do if i want to assign different class/id to the each option after selecting them ?

Comment: write this code in `$(this).addClass("className");`  click function

Comment: does this assign different classes to different selected options ?